# how do I remove unwanted empty dimension from xarray DataArray (squeeze doesn't work)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a DataArray that has four dimension, as you can see time has a size of 0:

```
<xarray.DataArray (color: 3, time: 0, y: 297, x: 496)>
array([], shape=(3, 0, 297, 496), dtype=float64)
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 -3.199e+06 -3.199e+06 -3.199e+06 -3.199e+06 ...
  * x        (x) float64 1.966e+06 1.966e+06 1.966e+06 1.966e+06 1.966e+06 ...
  * color    (color) 'red' 'green' 'blue'
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns]
```

I need my DataArray to be in the format ('Y','X','color') however when I try to get rid of the time dimension using squeeze:

```
new_darray = old_darray.squeeze('time')
```

this happens:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

and when I try this:

```
new_darray = old_darray[:,0,:,:]
```

this happens too:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't index or squeeze out a size 0 dimension, in either xarray or NumPy. That would entail transforming an empty array of size `3 * 0 * 279 * 496 = 0` into an array full of data of size `3 * 279 * 496 = 415152`. Where would the new data come from?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything with the data that doesn't exist, I'm trying to make a copy of the array with the data that does exist

Comment: I revised my answer to make it more explicit. Is that clearer?

Comment: @C.Crumpet: There **isn't any** "data that does exist". Your array is empty!